Duplicate lines when reading and writing into the same file
I have following simple code:
func updateRunSettingsFile(path string, logger *slog.Logger) error {

    fileRead, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer fileRead.Close()

    fileWrite, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer fileWrite.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(fileRead)

    for {
        var line string

        line, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                // done reading - this is not an error
                err = nil

                break
            }

            logger.Error("could not read from file", slog.String("error", err.Error()))

            break
        }

        if strings.Contains(line, "AAAA") {

            line = strings.ReplaceAll(line, "AAA", "BBB")
        }

        _, err = fileWrite.WriteString(line)
        if err != nil {
            logger.Error("could not write to file", slog.String("error", err.Error()))

            break
        }
    }

    return err
}

it should just replace any string that contains 'AAA' to 'BBB'. Everything is replaced but the file has additional (?) duplicated lines near the end.
For example the original file is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
   <Param1>AAA</Param1>
   <Param2>DDD</Param2>
   <SomeValue>Value</SomeValue>
</Configuration>

the file after replacement look like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
   <Param1>BBB</Param1>
   <Param2>DDD</Param2>
   <SomeValue>Value</SomeValue>
</Configuration>
lue</SomeValue>
</Configuration>

Why this happens ? It happens on Windows and Linux machines.. The source file is usual utf8 XML file
Update: Code has some logic error as @ZAkay mention in his answer about last line but this is not an issue. Something happens in reader or writer of defer call when somehow leftovers dumped into file at some point in time.... This is my question - where those leftovers are coming from ?

Interleaving writes and reads on a file is a tremendious dangerous idea and might (!!) work on some particular file systems. Just don't do that.

do the actual values for AAA and BBB have same length ? log fileWrite.Seek(1, 0) (<- the current position in file) after each write.

You can improve your question by adding more tags. Questions with one tag are rarely well received. You may be able to find tags related files, i/o, or text substitution

You can improve your question by saying why you want to do this.  If your problem is literally as simple as replacing AAA with BBB anywhere in the file, there are much simpler approaches such as using existing command line tools.  sed -i '' 's/AAA/BBB/g' <file> would do what you want with no need to write code. If you have greatly simplified your code to make a [mcve], that is fantastic, but you might want to say that your actual program is complicated enough that it can't be replicated by a sed one-liner.

Down votes here don't need to be explained. Some people may use down votes because similar questions have  been asked many times and they are sick of seeing them. It could be because somebody feels your question is too basic and you should be able to figure it out on your own.  It could be because somebody thinks you should scrap your "dangerous" implementation methodology and start over. These aren't necessarily good reasons for down votes, especially unexplained, but they happen.

Moderators can't tell who down voted or why. @ pinging moderators won't summon them.  (@ pings only work for people who have been active in the question already.)  The proper way to get a moderator is to flag the question for moderator attention.  However, a flag asking why there are down votes would be declined because moderators have no way of knowing that information.

@StephenOstermiller  because this is strange...  this is not a first question that was downvoted just like that..... but may be you right... may be it's too simple question...

@MarcLeBihan - the question here is about nuance in GO that I could not find info about. I personally and think other won't even look in question with downvotes to minus. Usually it is newbie question with very very basic question or incorrect description. So seeing your question thrown out of feed by unknown users by 'just because it Monday' reason - so sad..... Let me for example downvote current 100 new Python questions. Don't know Python and don't care about others - I don't think SO created for this.... So sad...


replace line = strings.ReplaceAll(line, line, "BBB") with strings.ReplaceAll(line, "AAAA", "BBB")
When Getting EOF line contains the last row. So you need to exit
after processing the last line.
I am not sure why you have
garbage, but i guess writing while reading open buffer, mess with the reader buffer.

I can suggest without testing:

Read all lines to memory change them and write all back to
the file. Use Go like sed
Write to another file.
If you can not create a new file and you don't have enough memory , try to replace from the end.


Yes.. I already implemented all of your suggestions already. As a workaround I open file with os.O_TRUNC access. This is strange because in another app I read just number of lines from file, change it and write back. Somehow lefovers added right after the last line... I didn't touch any buffers - the reader and writer code is exactly like in question. Something I don't understand in reader or in writer......
